# Geting error: Uncaught TypeError: (void 0) is not a function

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli

I am trying to start my application with angular-cli - ng serve. It compiles successfully, loading page gives: Uncaught TypeError: (void 0) is not a function in main.ts and polyfills.ts.

The application is angularjs and angular2. Have tried changing typescript versions and different tsconfig configurations, but same error appears

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "redis-cli",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "serve": "ng serve --mode=development",
    "build": "webpack --config webpack.config.js --mode=development",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.4.10",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.4.10",
    "@angular/http": "2.4.10",
    "@angular/core": "2.4.10",
    "@angular/forms": "2.4.10",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.4.10",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.4.10",
    "@angular/platform-server": "2.4.10",
    "@angular/router": "3.4.10",
    "@angular/upgrade": "2.4.10",
    "angular": "1.7.8",
    "angular-animate": "1.5.9",
    "angular-cookies": "1.5.9",
    "angular-elastic": "2.5.1",
    "angular-hotkeys": "^1.7.0",
    "angular-i18n": "1.5.9",
    "angular-loading-bar": "0.*",
    "angular-resource": "1.5.9",
    "angular-route": "1.5.9",
    "angular-sanitize": "1.5.9",
    "angular-scroll": "~0.7.1",
    "angular-touch": "^1.5.9",
    "angular-ui-bootstrap": "2.5.6",
    "angular-utf8-base64": "~0.0.5",
    "bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.7",
    "codelyzer": "4.4.4",
    "core-js": "2.5.3",
    "crypto-js": "3.1.9-1",
    "cryptojslib": "~3.1.2",
    "daterangepicker": "^3.0.3",
    "enhanced-resolve": "^3.3.0",
    "eslint": "^3.9.1",
    "eslint-html-reporter": "^0.5.2",
    "eslint-plugin-angular": "^1.4.1",
    "eslint-plugin-nortal": "0.0.1",
    "fileapi": "2.0.25",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "3.0.7",
    "isikukood": "1.2.3",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "lodash": "3.10.1",
    "message-center": "^0.1.10",
    "moment": "2.9.0",
    "ng-file-upload": "3.2.*",
    "ng-table": "0.5.*",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "1.6.2",
    "oi.select": "^0.2.21",
    "pako": "1.0.6",
    "rxjs": "^5.0.1",
    "split.js": "^1.3.5",
    "ua-parser-js": "0.7.18",
    "ui-router": "^1.0.0-alpha.3",
    "webpack-merge": "^3.0.0",
    "yarn": "^1.17.3",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.2",
    "tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin": "3.2.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.7.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "2.4.10",
    "@types/google.analytics": "0.0.39",
    "@types/jquery": "<3.3.28",
    "@types/node": "^12.0.5",
    "angular2-template-loader": "^0.6.0",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "^3.0.4",
    "tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin": "3.2.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "0.8.0",
    "html-loader": "^0.4.3",
    "css-loader": "^0.26.1",
    "grunt": "0.4.0",
    "tslint": "^5.0.0",
    "typescript": "2.6.1",
    "webpack": "^4.4.0",
    "webpack-cli": "3.3.6",
    "webpack-dev-server": "3.4.1",
    "webpack-merge": "^3.0.0"
  }
}
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMaps": false,
    "allowJs": true,
    "module": "system",
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "noStrictGenericChecks": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noImplicitThis": false,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "strictNullChecks": false,
    "outputHashing": "all",
    "extractCss": true,
    "namedChunks": false,
    "buildOptimizer": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "target": "es6",
    "files": [
      "node_modules/moment/moment.d.ts"
    ],
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es6",
      "dom",
      "scripthost"
    ],
    "types": [
      "node",
      "google.analytics",
      "jquery"
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@tet/*": [
        "app-cli/modules/*",
        "/common/app/modules/*"
      ],
      "@angular/*": ["../node_modules/@angular/*"]
    },
    "exclude": [
      "node_modules"
    ]
  }
}
```

webpack.dev.js

```
var webpackMerge = require('webpack-merge');
var MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
var commonConfig = require('./webpack.common.js');
var helpers = require('./helpers');
var TsconfigPathsPlugin = require('tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = webpackMerge(commonConfig, {
  devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',

  output: {
    path: helpers.root('dist'),
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: '[name].js',
    chunkFilename: '[id].chunk.js'
  },

  plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({filename: '[name].css'})
  ],

  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    stats: 'minimal'
  },
  resolve: {
    plugins: [new TsconfigPathsPlugin({ configFile: "./tsconfig.json" })]
  }
});
```

webpack.common.js

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
var helpers = require('./helpers');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    'app-cli': './app-cli/main.ts'
  },

  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.js']
  },

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        loaders: [
          {
            loader: 'awesome-typescript-loader',
            options: { configFileName: 'tsconfig.json' }
          } , 'angular2-template-loader'
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        loader: 'html-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|eot|ico)$/,
        loader: 'file-loader?name=assets/[name].[hash].[ext]'
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        exclude: helpers.root('app-cli'),
        use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader']
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        include: helpers.root('app-cli'),
        loader: 'raw-loader'
      }
    ]
  },

  plugins: [
    // Workaround for angular/angular#11580
    new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
      // The (\\|\/) piece accounts for path separators in *nix and Windows
      /angular(\\|\/)core(\\|\/)@angular/,
      helpers.root('./app-cli'), // location of your src
      {} // a map of your routes
    ),

    // new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
    //   name: ['app-cli']
    // }),

    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: 'app-cli/index.html'
    })
  ]
};
```

main.ts

```
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { environment } from './environment/environment';
import { AppModule } from '@tet/app.module';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

polyfills.ts

```
/**
 * This file includes polyfills needed by Angular and is loaded before the app.
 * You can add your own extra polyfills to this file.
 *
 * This file is divided into 2 sections:
 *   1. Browser polyfills. These are applied before loading ZoneJS and are sorted by browsers.
 *   2. Application imports. Files imported after ZoneJS that should be loaded before your main
 *      file.
 *
 * The current setup is for so-called "evergreen" browsers; the last versions of browsers that
 * automatically update themselves. This includes Safari >= 10, Chrome >= 55 (including Opera),
 * Edge >= 13 on the desktop, and iOS 10 and Chrome on mobile.
 *
 * Learn more in https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/browser-support.html
 */

/***************************************************************************************************
 * BROWSER POLYFILLS
 */

/** IE9, IE10 and IE11 requires all of the following polyfills. **/
import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
import 'core-js/es6/object';
import 'core-js/es6/function';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
import 'core-js/es6/number';
import 'core-js/es6/math';
import 'core-js/es6/string';
import 'core-js/es6/date';
import 'core-js/es6/array';
import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
import 'core-js/es6/map';
import 'core-js/es6/weak-map';
import 'core-js/es6/set';

/** IE10 and IE11 requires the following for NgClass support on SVG elements */
import 'classlist.js';  // Run `npm install --save classlist.js`.

/** Evergreen browsers require these. **/
import 'core-js/es6/reflect';
import 'core-js/es7/reflect';

/**
 * Required to support Web Animations `@angular/animation`.
 * Needed for: All but Chrome, Firefox and Opera. http://caniuse.com/#feat=web-animation
 **/
import 'web-animations-js';  // Run `npm install --save web-animations-js`.



/***************************************************************************************************
 * Zone JS is required by Angular itself.
 */
import 'zone.js/dist/zone';  // Included with Angular CLI.



/***************************************************************************************************
 * APPLICATION IMPORTS
 */

/**
 * Date, currency, decimal and percent pipes.
 * Needed for: All but Chrome, Firefox, Edge, IE11 and Safari 10
 */
import 'intl';  // Run `npm install --save intl`.
/**
 * Need to import at least one locale-data with intl.
 */
import 'intl/locale-data/jsonp/en';
```

Error:

```
VM1169 polyfills.ts:16 Uncaught TypeError: (void 0) is not a function
    at eval (VM1169 polyfills.ts:16)
    at Object../app-cli/polyfills.ts (VM1168 polyfills.bundle.js:6)
    at __webpack_require__ (VM1167 inline.bundle.js:55)
    at Object.1 (VM1168 polyfills.bundle.js:13)
    at __webpack_require__ (VM1167 inline.bundle.js:55)
    at webpackJsonpCallback (VM1167 inline.bundle.js:26)
    at VM1168 polyfills.bundle.js:1
(anonymous) @ VM1169 polyfills.ts:16
./app-cli/polyfills.ts @ VM1168 polyfills.bundle.js:6
__webpack_require__ @ VM1167 inline.bundle.js:55
1 @ VM1168 polyfills.bundle.js:13
__webpack_require__ @ VM1167 inline.bundle.js:55
webpackJsonpCallback @ VM1167 inline.bundle.js:26
(anonymous) @ VM1168 polyfills.bundle.js:1
VM1210 main.ts:1 Uncaught TypeError: (void 0) is not a function
    at eval (VM1210 main.ts:1)
    at Object../app-cli/main.ts (VM1186 main.bundle.js:6)
    at __webpack_require__ (VM1167 inline.bundle.js:55)
    at Object.0 (VM1186 main.bundle.js:21)
    at __webpack_require__ (VM1167 inline.bundle.js:55)
    at webpackJsonpCallback (VM1167 inline.bundle.js:26)
    at VM1186 main.bundle.js:1
```

main.bundle.js

```
(void 0)(["@angular/core", "./environment/environment", "@tet/app.module", "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic"], function (exports_1, context_1) {
    "use strict";
    var __moduleName = context_1 && context_1.id;
    var core_1, environment_1, app_module_1, platform_browser_dynamic_1;
    return {
        setters: [
            function (core_1_1) {
                core_1 = core_1_1;
            },
            function (environment_1_1) {
                environment_1 = environment_1_1;
            },
            function (app_module_1_1) {
                app_module_1 = app_module_1_1;
            },
            function (platform_browser_dynamic_1_1) {
                platform_browser_dynamic_1 = platform_browser_dynamic_1_1;
            }
        ],
        execute: function () {
            if (environment_1.environment.production) {
                core_1.enableProdMode();
            }
            platform_browser_dynamic_1.platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(app_module_1.AppModule);
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: Are you sure this is a minimal example showing the error?

Comment: Problem comes from main.bundle.js. Added the file content.